# How to call handle_event with params without using a form?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

How do I call handle_event wish specific params without using a form?

I'd like table row details to be displayed in a modal when row_click happens. I am able to trigger handle events, but params are always `%{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs about [click events](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/bindings.html#click-events) to read more about event parameters and about [JS commands](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/bindings.html#js-commands).

You can use [`JS.push`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.JS.html#push/1) to send an event (with params) or use any other of the [JS functions](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.JS.html#functions).

That was the short answer, now the long answer, hopefully more specific to your second question. If not, you should have provided more details. ;p

### Show a modal with table row details

I'm going to assume we just created a new Phoenix project, ran `mix phx.gen.live Blog Post posts title:string body:text` and followed the instructions to create a new live view. The goal is to click on a table row in the index view and show a modal with the table row details.

In `index.html.heex` there already is a modal for the `new` and `edit` actions. Let's add a modal for the `show` action right below it:

```
<.modal :if={@live_action == :show} id="post-show-modal" show on_cancel={JS.patch(~p"/posts")}>
  <h1 class="text-lg font-semibold leading-8 text-zinc-800"><%= @post.title %></h1>
  <p class="mt-2 text-sm leading-6 text-zinc-600"><%= @post.body %></p>
</.modal>
```

We want this modal to open when a table row is clicked, but right now the `row_click` function of the table navigates to `/posts/#{post}` wich is routed to the `PostLive.Show` view. Let's change that by routing the `show` route/action to `PostLive.Index`. In `router.ex` change the line:

```
live "/posts/:id", PostLive.Show, :show
# to
live "/posts/:id", PostLive.Index, :show
```

and add a corresponding action to the `PostLive.Index` module (`post_live/index.ex`):

```
  defp apply_action(socket, :show, %{"id" => id}) do
    socket
    |> assign(:page_title, "Show Post")
    |> assign(:post, Blog.get_post!(id))
  end
```

Now everything is wired up and when a table row is clicked, the show modal opens.

To improve on this a bit more, change the `row_click` function of the table to use `patch` instead of `navigate`, because we navigate to the same live module (more about that [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/live-navigation.html)):

```
row_click={fn {_id, post} -> JS.patch(~p"/posts/#{post}") end}
```